# Mercurial and subrepos with multiple sibling folders

Tags: mercurial

Suppose I have this folder structure:

- ParentFolder

  - A1
  - A2
  - A3
  - B
  - C

Is it possible to preserve the above folder structure and have 3 Mercurial subrepos A, B, C where:

- A: contains folders A1, A2, A3
- B contains folder B
- C contains folder C

Again, I do not want to create a subrepo A that will have A1, A2, A3 as subfolders, I am looking for a way to preserve the file structure above.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible way is to achieve this would be to create a repository `A` which contains `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and also the repositories `B` and `C` as subrepositories.

- ParentFolder (subrepository of `A`)

  - A1
  - A2
  - A3
  - B (subrepository of `B` in `A`)
  - C (subrepository of `C` in `A`)

Since you cannot clone just a part of a repository, you cannot do it otherwise.